# How to get outline of a pdf using pdftron package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdftron

pdftron has their existing method for getting pdf outline in the app.
This is what pdftron gives us https://ibb.co/bdkZdcR

Problem is I can't find their method that they used in the package for dart/flutter.
I can't have any access on the outline.i

I want to get these outlines as xml or an object so that I can use them.

Answer (score 0):

The PDFTron Flutter project is a convenience wrapper around the native PDFTron platform SDKs for Android and iOS, where you will find APIs to interact with and manipulate a document's outline (a "bookmark" in PDF terminology - not to be confused with "user bookmarks"):

- [PDF outline sample for iOS (Swift)](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/swift/BookmarkTest/?platforms=ios)
- [PDF outline sample for Android (Java)](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/android/java/BookmarkTest?platforms=android)

Currently there is no equivalent API in the Flutter wrapper for operating on a document's outline, but it is something that could be added in the future. If this is something that you'd like to see added to the Flutter wrapper then you can add it as a suggestion on the GitHub project's repo: https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-flutter

You can open the outline-list UI control programmatically with [this API](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdftron_flutter/latest/pdftron/PdftronFlutter/openOutlineList.html) though, if that works for your use case.